# sequential and parallel processing of promises

Tags: javascript, promise

The idea is to sequentially iterate the array but parallel process each item in the subarray.

1. Once record #1 is processed in parallel then it moves to the record #2 and parallel process it's items and so on. So basically it's a combination of sequentiality and parallelism.
2. Concat all results in a single dimension array and display. (pending)

If input contains an array of arrays.

```
var items = [
    ["item1", "item2"],
    ["item3", "item4"],
    ["item5", "item6"],
    ["item7", "item8"],
    ["item9", "item10"]
]
```

And an action that processes these items.

```
function action(item) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        setTimeout(function(){
            resolve(item + ":processed");
        }, 100)
    });
}
```

**Attempt**

```
describe("", function(){
    this.timeout(0);

    it("should", function(done){
        items.reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex, array){
            return accumulator.then(function(result){
                return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                    Promise.all(currentValue.map(action))
                        .then(resolve, reject);
                });
            });
        }, Promise.resolve())

    });

});
```

**Expectations**:

Ideally a clean minimalistic and a *functional approach* (**no state**) to return the results to the caller.

---

**Attempt 2**

```
var chain = items.reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex, array){
    return accumulator.then(function(result){
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            Promise.all(currentValue.map(action))
                .then(resolve, reject);
        });
    });
}, Promise.resolve());

chain.then(console.log, console.error); // I need all results here
```

> > displays last result only. [ 'item9:processed', 'item10:processed' ]

---

**Edit** final solution based on the answer.

```
var chain = items.reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex, array){
    return accumulator.then(function(result){
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

            Promise.all(currentValue.map(action))
                .then(function(data){
                    resolve(result.concat(data)) // new array
                }, reject);
        });

    });
}, Promise.resolve([]));

chain.then(console.log, console.error);
```

Comment: *...and display. (pending)* Finally when flattened not all of them might be in pending state though.

Comment: sorry, I meant pending in the sense that I'm not done with atm, not the promise pending :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this:

```js
var items = [
    ["item1", "item2"],
    ["item3", "item4"],
    ["item5", "item6"],
    ["item7", "item8"],
    ["item9", "item10"]
]

function action(item) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        setTimeout(function(){
            resolve(item + ":processed");
        }, 100)
    });
}

function process(items) {
  return items.reduce((m, d) => {
    const promises = d.map(i => action(i));
    let oldData;
    return m.then((data) => {
        oldData = data;
        return Promise.all(promises);
      })
      .then(values => {
        //oldData.push(...values);
        oldData.push.apply(oldData, values);
        return Promise.resolve(oldData);
      })
  }, Promise.resolve([]))
}

process(items).then(d => console.log(d))

//Prints:

// ["item1:processed","item2:processed","item3:processed","item4:processed","item5:processed","item6:processed","item7:processed","item8:processed","item9:processed","item10:processed"]
```

Comment: Thanks Chirag, I've got the idea, can you enlighten me more on the array concat part using plain javascript, I'm not on es6 yet.

Comment: the functional approach would be to return new arrays instead of pushing into old values (aka state)

Comment: `oldData.push(...values);` uses the ES6 spread operator.. Have re-written it using apply for your reference

Comment: is there a way to return a totally new array combing both result and data instead of using push, `result.push.apply`, the idea is to use functional approach with assuming all inputs are immutable.

Comment: @App2015 I'm not sure that this approach violates the functional approach. The function `process` does not mutate any objects passed to it. It internally creates a new array and adds to that and returns a promise which resolves with the newly created array.

Comment: got the idea? like there's no mutation going on with the `oldData`, please edit your answer so it may help others too.

Comment: @App2015 I understand what you mean.. I still believe that the function `process` adheres to the functional programming paradigm.. It uses a fixed array internally, yes.. But that shouldn't make it 'non-functional' or mean that it 'mutates data' because it returns a Promise which resolves with a 'fresh array' created by the function (and does not change/mutate the arguments passed to it). But then again, I'm no expert.. Glad you got it working the way you wanted to :)

Comment: under strict functional programming they say every array that you create has to be final, if it needs to be mutated (`push`) that means array wasn't created the right values. in my edit I depicted that neither of the incoming params or local vars (`oldData`) are to mutated, I learned a great deal about these things in F# and opted because you can really learn things only in it's constrained environment/language :)

Comment: I see. I always understood it as 'not changing things given to the function to keep the code easily reasonable'.. I haven't really worked on 'strictly functional' languages.. I use the guidelines of functional programming more as a 'best-practice' and must admit that I haven't really dived in deep and can't really argue your points constructively. I opened [a question on Codereview StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/191567/does-this-function-break-the-paradigm-of-functional-programming-in-js)  feel free to drop in your two cents :)

Comment: I saw the response, the point is to avoid mutation, Core Concepts: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEUOG.jpg Code Smell: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WI3Oj.jpg Good https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPP8q.jpg

Comment: above screenshots are from https://www.lynda.com/JavaScript-tutorials/What-functional-programming/585272/634532-4.html. I also recommend learning F# or Haskell if you want to go extreme, if you can to really get used to these constraints, it seems impossible to do anything without mutation but you'll find the way and will turn out to be cleaner and easier way. I dived into them to learn concepts in constrained environment and now I look at Javascript differently from what I was used to.

Answer (score 0):

A simple functional way of doing this would be like

- map sub array with parallel data by promise returning async functions
- `Promise.all()` the resulting promises array
- sequence the sub arrays at the `.then()` stage of `Promise.all() in a recursive fashion`

ES6; tools like [`spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) / [`rest parameters`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) and [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring) are very handy for this job.

```js
var items = [["item1", "item2"],
             ["item3", "item4"],
             ["item5", "item6"],
             ["item7", "item8"],
             ["item9", "item10"]],
    act   = i => new Promise(v => setTimeout(v, 1000, `${i}: processed`)),
    seqps = ([is,...iss]) => is && Promise.all(is.map(i => act(i)))
                                          .then(([p,q]) => (console.log(`${p} and ${q}`),
                                                            seqps(iss)));
seqps(items);
```